# Как передать комманду запущенному процессу в node.js?

Tags: node.js

Я запускаю бинарный файл на node.js

```
 const app = spawn('./app', ['-D']);
```

stdout я получаю в консоли.

Как мне передать комманду для выполнения.

Например вывести help.